# regular expression [\a-z]

Tags: regex

difference between `[a-z]` and `[\a-z]`. The first one does not contain space `' '` in the range but the second one is matching for space `' '`. Why??

Comment: Because `\a` = ASCII code 7

Comment: ... and the characters from code 7 to character z (code 122) include the space and other characters.

Comment: One of you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`[a-z]` matches a character from `a` to `z`

`[\a-z]` matches a character from `\a` to `z`

`\a` is not `a`. According to regex101.com \a matches the bell character (ASCII 7). I don't know what this character is but it looks like whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

`\a` is ASCII code 7 (bell). `a-z` would be the range of characters a through z.

So `\a-z` is the range of characters from `\a` to the character `z` (index 122) which includes the space character (and many others).

An [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) confirms the range of characters covered.

---

If you wanted to allow for a backslash in addition to the characters a through z, then use `[a-z\\]` (the backslash needs to be escaped). [I moved it to the end as I find this version clearer.]